# magento 2.1 - Automatic Creation of Categories During Product Import

Tags: zend-framework, import, magento2

I am trying to import 5000 products into magento 2.1 backend using a CSV file. The file also contains categories for the products and I aim to import the categories of the product as well.

During the import when categories are being created, the url-key assigned to them is blank. So when it goes to the next record and tries to create new categories, there is an error :

**"Category "A/B/C/" has not been created. URL key for specified store already exists".**

My understanding is that since the import mechanism is unable to create proper url-key based on category name, then a blank entry is put as url-key and the next category to import which also has a blank url-key identifies a duplicate and throws an exception.

Does anyone know a way to set a default mechanism, to generate url-key based on category name during import process?

Thanks!